# Hive and RJDBC: Datatype date is not detected -> thus: converted to dataframe R column type "character"

Tags: r, hadoop, rstudio, jdbc

I am using R-Studio to process data from HIVE. Here I am using RJDBC.  RJDBC converts the select statement into a dataframe. Unfortunately conversion of hive columns data types "date" and "timestamp" seems not be recognized. Thus it is converted as character during dbReadTable(conn, db2.ibor_lending), which is bad.

Do you have any idea about this ? I don't want to recast the character to date again in R because it is 1. overhead, 2. lead to coupling and 3. increased maintenance efforts

```
library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

print("Attempting Hive Connection...")

hadoop.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client"),pattern="jar", full.names=T);
hadoop.client.lib = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib"),pattern="jar", full.names=T);
hive.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib"),pattern="jar", full.names=T);
hadoop.hdfs.lib.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client"),pattern="jar",full.names=T);
zookeeper.lib.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client"),pattern="jar",full.names=T);
mapred.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client"),pattern="jar",full.names=T);


cp = c(hive.class.path,mapred.class.path,hadoop.class.path,hadoop.client.lib,hadoop.hdfs.lib.path)
.jinit(classpath=cp, parameters="-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false")

drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver","/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-jdbc.jar",identifier.quote="`")

conn <- dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:hive2://xxx:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=hive/_HOST@yyyy")

show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from db2.ibor_lending LIMIT 100")
show_datatypes <- dbGetQuery(conn, "describe db2.ibor_lending")

show_table <- dbReadTable(conn, db2.ibor_lending)
```

The result is:

```
          Hive:              col_name data_type comment
                             cutoffdate timestamp        

          R dataframe:       ibor_lending.cutoffdate character
```

Br,  Dennis

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?